# Updating properties of an item within an observable array in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement an updatable "selected item" of an observable array in Knockout, such that changes on the selected item's properties get propagated back to the list.

In the following example, my model contains a list of users in an observable array, with each user having an observable 'name' property. The model also has a `selectedUser` property, which references a user in the list.

I have an input control bound to the `name()` value of the selected user. I want to be able to change the name within the input, and see that change propagate to the list below.

**JS:**

```
var UserModel = function() {
    this.users = ko.observableArray([
                {id:1, name:ko.observable('Bob')},
                {id:2, name:ko.observable('Jane')}
            ]);
    this.selectedUser = ko.observable(this.users()[0]);
    console.log(this.users()[0].name());
}
ko.applyBindings(UserModel);
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedUser().name()" value="">
<table data-bind="foreach: users()">
    <tr >
        <td data-bind="text: $data.name()"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5t5k2/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're *almost* there.

The only problem is that you're binding the input field to an *invocation* of the observable and not the function itself.

When you do `.name()` you're invoking the observable so you get a string back. Instead, bind to the observable itself.

Change:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedUser().name()" value="">
```

to

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedUser().name" value="">
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KkP6f/) )

If you want that immediate feel, you can tell it to update on key down too and not just on the change event (that fires on tab or when you lose focus)

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedUser().name, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" value="">
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Vt8m/) )

Comment: Any time :) I think binding to the result of an observable and not the observable itself got me quite a few times too.